# How to show the value in dropdown

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 dropdown in different components I want when user click on A option it's reflect in other options which is placed in another component like if user click on B option then other component option also show the value B in option
How can I do that?
I am fetching the A and B from api local host

Comment: could you please show us your code? what have you done so far?

Comment: Please take a *breath*. Also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)